# Matching UK postcodes to shipping rules

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce, shipping

I'm in the process of setting up an e-commerce site using Exp:resso Store version 1.6.3. My client wants to be able to add surcharges to particular UK postcode areas based on the fact that they are hard to reach regions.

I assumed this would be easy using the Standard Shipping Plugin, by adding different rules for the first part of each postcode.

For example, if we wanted to surcharge all customers with postcodes starting 'AB', I would simply add a rule to match postcode 'AB' and apply a charge to that. I'm not sure how to match this though as if I then complete a test order to the checkout confirmation page with postcode 'AB34 3DP', this rule is ignored.

In addition, I would not want to apply this rule if the customer postcode was, for example 'TN4 3AB'. Is there a method to add wildcards to the postcode shipping rules? I could not find any information in the Exp:resso Store docs.

Comment: Can you email support@exp-resso.com? I have an updated version of Store with support for matching post codes using wildcards for you to test :)

Answer (score 2):

This has been implemented in [Store 1.6.4](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/release_notes.html).

You can now use wildcards when entering postcodes, such as `AB*`, and it will match all postcodes starting with AB. As well as `*` to match any number of characters, you can also use `?` to represent any single character - for example, `123?` would match `1234` and `1235`, but not `12345`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. Updated from 1.6.3 to 1.6.4