# UK Postcode Shipping Rules - more than one postcode per rule

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce, shipping

I'm using Exp-resso Store to run the ecommerce functionality of my site. I've upgraded to 1.6.4 which allows me to add rules for different UK postcodes, as per this question:

[Matching UK postcodes to shipping rules](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6636/matching-uk-postcodes-to-shipping-rules)

The problem being is that my client's shipping rules are going to be fairly complex, in that I have about 30 different rules for each postcode depending if its mainland UK or highland/island/Northern Ireland.

My client has then dropped the bombshell that they can pack two items into a package and therefore prices should be for every two items, i.e. 0-2 items at £15, 3-4 items at £30, 5-6 items at £45, etc. If I combine these with 30 existing rules for postcodes, you can see that I am already in several hundred rules! A nightmare for me or the client to update...

My question is, is there a way of adding more than one postcode per rule? Or another way for me to price per items?

I think an image of my rules will help clarify things:

[image]

EDIT:

Sorry, I should mention that I've looked in the Docs and there's nothing obvious there, however I may have missed this. I've tried the obvious "IV1 *, IV2 *" and "IV1 *|IV2 *" (without the quotes) but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to specify multiple postcodes per shipping rule, although I do like your pipe-separated syntax so will make that a feature request.

As you mentioned, it is going to be a nightmare for your client to maintain, so I would first explain this to them and convince them to simplify their shipping rules.

The other alternative would be to write a custom shipping plugin in PHP, which would allow you to use any combination of rules you like, but that will probably be even harder for them to maintain/update so may not be the best solution.

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for getting back to me. I was afraid you were going to say that...

Thanks for making this a feature request. I suspect I won't be the only person who will experience this, at least regarding the highlands/islands/Northern Ireland part anyway. Stupid UK postcodes!

Cool, I shall report back to my client and go from there.

Thanks.